# Removing nodes between two given positions from singly linked list?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am teaching myself data structures and following to Java books on this subject. Currently I am learning Linked List implementation. I have been struggling with how to write a method which takes "startPos" and "endPos" and simply removes the nodes accordingly. I am validating "startPos", and "endPos" in order to catch invalid position input. I have Googled for direction but have not come across any online example that can help me get going with this logic. I would highly appreciate any guidance with this please. Thank you.

```
class Node{

   public Object data;
   public Node next;

}
```

Delete Nodes Method

```
  public void deleteNodes( int startPos, int endPos ){         
      Node node = _nHead;
      int counter = 0;

  if( startPos < 1 || startPos > getSize() )
      return;

  if( endPos < 1 || endPos > getSize() ) 
      return;


  while( node != null){

    node = node.next;
    ++counter;
  }
}
```

GET SIZE

```
public int getSize(){

    int counter = 0;

    for( Node node = _nHead; node != null; node = node.next )
    ++counter;
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all nodes between two nodes on a singly linked list is not super hard.

You need two placeholders.  You move through the linked list until you find your start node, and set one of the placeholders equal to it.  You then move your second placeholder through the remainder of the linked list until you find your second node.  Set your first node's -> next parameter equal to the second node, and you've effectively removed everything in between.

For proper cleanup, you should keep track of the node that was next after the first node and free all nodes that were removed from memory, but this is more critical in C than Java.

For a doubly-linked list the method is similar, except you also have to set the second node's previous to the first node.

As an example:

```
public void deleteNodes( int startPos, int endPos ){         
    Node node = _nHead;
    Node start;
    Node end;

    int counter = 0;

    if( startPos < 1 || startPos > getSize() )
        return;

    if( endPos < 1 || endPos > getSize() ) 
        return;

    if (endPos < startPos)
    {
        int placeholder = startPos;
        startPos = endPos;
        endPos = placeholder;   // switches end and start if start is greater than end
    }

    if (endPos == startPos)
        return; // if they are equal we aren't deleting anything;


    while( node != null)
    {
        if (counter == startPos)
            start = node;

        if (counter == endPos)
            end = node;

        node = node.next;
        counter++;
    }

    if (start != NULL && end != NULL)
    {
        start.next = end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply have to set the next pointer of the node at the start of the removal range to the node at the end of the removal range. Since there would be no references to the nodes in the delete range, Java's garbage collection should clear them up.